# YII: How to achieve different routing if there are GET parameters?

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager

In the Yii URL manager, I'd like to define a different route for a URL if there are GET parameters attached. For example, the URL 'shopping-wizard/' should go to the route shoppingWizard/index, and the URL 'shopping-wizard/?answer=10' should go to the route shoppingWizard/result.

I've tried the following rules:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'rules'=>array(
        'shopping-wizard/?answer=<answer>' => 'shoppingWizard/result',
        'shopping-wizard/' => 'shoppingWizard/index',
    ),
),
```

This does not work, because CUrlRule::parseUrl() adds a trailing slash to the pattern. My URL with parameter may not have a trailing slash for SEO reasons.

It does work with a URL rule component, but is there a simpler way to do it? Without a separate component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rule like this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'rules'=>array(
        'shopping-wizard/<answer:\d+>' => 'shoppingWizard/result', //d+ - digits only
        'shopping-wizard/' => 'shoppingWizard/index',
    ),
),
```

And in your controller:

```
public function actionResult($answer) {
    ...
}
```